# How to fix associative array keys that lack single quotation marks in multiple files

Tags: php, regex, bash, sed, replace

I've been assigned a project that have associative arrays without single quotes all over the place.

Example:

```
$foo[bar]
```

Which should be:

```
$foo['bar']
```

This generates a PHP notice and it's very bad practice.

Quoting from [PHP.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php):

> This is wrong, but it works. The reason is that this code has an
>   undefined constant (bar) rather than a string ('bar' - notice the
>   quotes). PHP may in future define constants which, unfortunately for
>   such code, have the same name. It works because PHP automatically
>   converts a bare string (an unquoted string which does not correspond
>   to any known symbol) into a string which contains the bare string. For
>   instance, if there is no defined constant named bar, then PHP will
>   substitute in the string 'bar' and use that.

And it's not good for performance because it has to search for a constant, before using `'key'`

So I was wondering if someone knows a script that can achieve this without having to do it manually in a one by one basis for every file.

**UPDATE:**

I use Vim as an editor, and I know how to use its search and replace command in a single file, however I see two problems with this:

1. I can't search and replace something like this because I don't think it supports regular expressions.
2. It only works in the current opened file (as far as I know).

Comment: It might be very hard if there are places where constants are really used.

Comment: If your are sure no constant is used, here is an how-to using utility sed and regexps: http://chris.olstrom.com/howto/replace-text-in-multiple-files/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your text editor not support global search and replace using regular expressions?

I might search for something like:

`(\$[a-zA-Z0-9]+\[)([^\]]+)\]`

and replace with

`\1'\2']`

Regular expression search+replace is really useful for broad changes to lots of source files.  Although make sure you take a snapshot of your code before you make the global change and verify afterwards that everything you wanted changed was changed with no unintended side-effects.

UPDATE:

Based on OP's update that s/he is using vim, see the accepted answer of this post: [Apply regular expression substitution globally to many files with a script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3225477/apply-regular-expression-substitution-globally-to-many-files-with-a-script) which describes using regular expression search/replace on multiple files in vim.

The sed-like syntax suggests to me that the command you are looking for (untested) is:

`:args **/*.php | argdo %s/(\$[a-zA-Z0-9]+\[)([^\]]+)\]/\1'\2'/ge | update`

You might need to fiddle with that a bit, so make a backup before you go modifying all your files.  I recommend trying to find a more user-friendly IDE as well.

Comment: The regular expression didn't work, however I think you have pointed out the right way to resolve this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Does you IDE do a search and replace? If so use that. It might take some time but you need to be careful with just changing all of them in one go.

Answer (score 1):

This would be another possible solution with vim:

```
:%s/\[\(\h*\)\]/\['\1'\]/gc
```

This would change all instances of:

```
[foo]
```

To:

```
['foo']
```

And will prompt for confirmation.

The following examples would remain unchanged (as they should be):

```
[$foo]
["foo"]
['foo']
[123]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an IDE to do a find and replace on the project. Most of them allow you to put a regex in the search string, so whenever it matches the pattern replace `[` with `['` and `]` with `']`.