# Square brackets with a class name inside in PHP

Tags: php

I'm debugging someone else old code, I think it has been made under php5 and I'm debugging after migrating to php8.
The question I have is just about a syntax I haven't seen before, I don't know how to google and I can't test.
I found this:

`$aSelectedAssignmentFields=$advanced_options[assignment_fields];`

And I don't know what it means. The value inside of the square brackets doesn't have a dollar sign or quotes. There is a class with that name but because of other issues I can't run it and check if that's right or wrong. It would be weird that is wrong, it would not that is outdated and in case it's right I would like to know what does it mean.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe this help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14891464/how-to-fix-associative-array-keys-that-lack-single-quotation-marks-in-multiple-f

Comment: `var_dump($advanced_options)` and check if it has a key `assignment_fields`. I _guess_ they just forgot the quotes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's impossible to do more than guess without more context; and may be impossible to be certain without a time machine to go back and ask the original developer (if you asked them now, I doubt they'd remember). I can think of two possibilities:

1. It was intended to be a constant, and the definition has got lost somewhere. Most people right constants in upper-case, but there's never been anything in PHP itself to enforce that.
2. It was intended to be a string, as in `$aSelectedAssignmentFields=$advanced_options['assignment_fields'];` Prior to PHP 8, there was an odd "feature" where an unquoted name which didn't match a constant would implicitly act like a quoted string. In PHP 5, it would have given a Notice; in PHP 7, a Warning; and in PHP 8, the functionality was removed and you get an error.

Comment: Sure. I know what you mean. But you answered me already. It is a syntax error under php8. Most probably your second possibility, because I have found that syntax everywhere.

Comment: If you turn on `error_reporting` on your pre-8 app installs you'll likely see a boatload of warning/notice messages. This has never been acceptable, but as of PHP8 it is not longer ignorable. https://3v4l.org/67KOM