# In Vim, how do I delete everything but keep what is in double quotes?

Tags: vim

I have multiple lines of plain texts and each line is mixed with phrases with/without double quotes. I want to delete everything including quotes but keep what's in double quotes. 
Example:

```
this is some test = "key.properties";
properties = "value.properties";
```

Result should be:

```
key.properties
value.properties
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3225477/apply-regular-expression-substitution-globally-to-many-files-with-a-script

Comment: Another option `%norm df";d$`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:%s/.*\"\(.*\)\".*/\1`

Explanation

```
REPLACE, ANY_STRING, QUOTES, CAPTURE_ANY_STRING,   QUOTES,  ANY_STRING WITH
  :%s/     .*        \"      \(     .*     \)       \"         .* .    /\1
```

Answer (score 1):

If your cursor is at the start of the line, you can do:

```
f"lyi"Vp
```

`f"l` move cursor to first " then left one more space

`yi"` yank everything within the "s to the anonymous register

`Vp` select the whole line in visual mode and paste the anonymous register over it

To apply to multiple lines, use the `normal` command.

```
:%normal 0f"lyi"Vp
```

`:` enter command mode

`%` set the range as the whole file

`normal` execute the following key strokes as if they were entered in normal mode

`0` move cursor to start of line

`f"lyi"Vp` see above

Comment: It does works for individual line. is there a way ( like search and replace ) to do it for multiple line without repeating for each line.

Comment: @yantaq Edited. If you need to do this to multiple files, then there are resources out there for doing so, but I would personally recommend using other tools than Vim.